# After reinstall Android Studio--Failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

Tags: android

I uninstalled Android 1.4, and then installed Android 1.3 with API 15.  When I run the project, it has following errors.
[image]

I want to use the old version of Android Studio (1.3), it seems that I have to install the latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- click on android sdk manager icon
- click on android sdk
- in the android sdk location give link to your sdk
  it will look somthing like `C:\Users\......\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Comment: Thanks. You mean give link to my sdk. Where to give my link?which file?

Comment: if you have install it in c: drive  it looks like the link i have given above

Comment: but give this link to which file?I cannot copy and paste to a folder.

Comment: I mean where is android sdk location located? I am not quiet clear with that

Comment: Thanks, I found sdk location in sdk manager, but it is correct. why I still has that error?

Comment: I think it may caused by you don't have 23 API, Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if API-23 is installed.

Comment: I really don't want to use API-23, I prefer to use API-15.

Comment: "You can still build your app to support older versions, but setting the build target to the latest version allows you to enable new features and optimize your app for a great user experience on the latest devices."